# infinite scroll in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, infinite-scroll

I coded the below directive for infinite scroll, my problem which I couldn't figure out why it just fire once when the directive is loaded, I need your advice on how to make my list infinite-scroll.

I'm using it to get data remotely and each time i'm calling it I add to the counter 25, so each time it would return more data.

Thanx,

```js
angular.module('MyApp')
  .controller('InboxCtrl', function($scope, InboxFactory) {

    var counter = 0;

    $scope.loadData = function() {
      var promise = InboxFactory.getEvents(counter);
      promise.then(function(result) {
        $scope.events = result;
      });
      counter += 25;
    };

  });

angular.module('MyApp')
  .factory('InboxFactory', function($http, $q) {
    // Service logic

    var defered = $q.defer();

    function getUrl(count) {
      return "api/inbox/get?request={'what':'Search','criteria':'inbox','criteriaId':null,'startTime':null,'endTime':null,'offset':" + count + ",'limit':25,'order':'event_time','direction':'DESC','source':''}";
    }

    function extract(result) {
      return result.data.data;
    }

    // Public API here
    return {
      getEvents: function(count) {
        $http.get(getUrl(count)).then(
          function(result) {
            defered.resolve(extract(result))
          }, function(err) {
            defered.reject(err);
          }
        );

        return defered.promise;
      }
    };
  });

angular.module('MyApp')
  .directive('infiniteScroll', ['$timeout',
    function(timeout) {
      return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
          var
            lengthThreshold = attr.scrollThreshold || 50,
            timeThreshold = attr.timeThreshold || 400,
            handler = scope.$eval(attr.infiniteScroll),
            promise = null,
            lastRemaining = 9999;

          lengthThreshold = parseInt(lengthThreshold, 10);
          timeThreshold = parseInt(timeThreshold, 10);

          if (!handler || !components.isFunction(handler)) {
            handler = components.noop;
          }

          element.bind('scroll', function() {
            var
              remaining = element[0].scrollHeight - (element[0].clientHeight + element[0].scrollTop);

            //if we have reached the threshold and we scroll down
            if (remaining < lengthThreshold && (remaining - lastRemaining) < 0) {

              //if there is already a timer running which has no expired yet we have to cancel it and restart the timer
              if (promise !== null) {
                timeout.cancel(promise);
              }
              promise = timeout(function() {
                handler();
                promise = null;
              }, timeThreshold);
            }
            lastRemaining = remaining;
          });
        }

      };
    }
  ]);
```

```html
<ul class="inbox-list" infinite-scroll="loadData()">
  <li class="clearfix" ng-repeat="event in events">{{event}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Made some changes the more important is the use of ng-transclude and the creation of a new scope for the directive to pass the method and the parameters. You can have a look at the [jsbind](http://jsbin.com/nuxopa/53/edit?html,css,js,output). Of course the data are hard coded so i could fake the behaviour.

```
<ul class="inbox-list" my-infinite-scroll composite-method="loadData()">
```

Comment: i changed Array.concat($scope.events, result); to [].concat($scope.events, result);. it is working on firefox and chrome. Before was working just in firefox